# WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /webapp/wcs/tools/servlet/ToolsLogon has not been defined

Tags: java, admin, websphere-commerce

I am getting the A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /webapp/wcs/tools/servlet/ToolsLogon has not been defined.when starting the admin console in Websphere commerce. can any one give me some info wt to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs when the wrong URL is used to access the tools.

**Resolving the problem**

Use the correct URLs for the tools, which are as follows:

WebSphere Commerce Accelerator : https://www.domain.com/webapp/wcs/tools/servlet/ToolsLogon?XMLFile=common.mcLogon

Administration Console : https://www.domain.com/webapp/wcs/admin/servlet/ToolsLogon?XMLFile=adminconsole.AdminConsoleLogon

Organization Administration Console : https://www.domain.com/webapp/wcs/orgadmin/servlet/ToolsLogon?XMLFile=buyerconsole.BuyAdminConsoleLogon